# Python print only specific key:value's from dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dict called 'data':

```
{'appconfigs': {'userAgent': None},
 'supported': [{'baseurl': 'mysite.com',
                'products': ['doll', 'toy'],
                'store': 'mysite1'},
               {'baseurl': 'mysite2.com',
                'products': ['doll', 'toy'],
                'store': 'mysite2'},
               {'baseurl': 'mysite3.com',
                'products': ['doll'],
                'store': 'mysite3'}]}
```

I want to print out a list of all the supported stores so it looks like:

```
mysite1
mysite2
mysite3
```

I thought something like print(data['supported.store']) would work but it doesn't - I'm clearly missing something here.

Comment: `for d in data['supported']:print(d['store'])`??

Comment: this works too, not sure if yours or @voids is a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you can do it in this way, you are going to use the supported key to loop in the supported stores from your data, then for each item you get, you are going to get three keys baseurl, products and store, using the store key in the item will return to you the store value

```
stores = [store["store"] for store in data["supported"] ]
```

Comment: can you explain what this part does? [store["store"]

Comment: the variable store is a dictionary that contains the baseurl, products and store keys along with their values, so to get only the store values, you should use its key hence "store", to do this simply write store["store"]

Answer (score 0):

```
stores = [data['supported'][i]['store'] for i in range(len(data['supported']))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data['supported'][0]['store']
```

gives the store of first element in the array

you want to use for i in data['supported'] to get all values as its an array

Answer (score 0):

To get the unique set of all stores:

```
stores = set(sup['store'] for sup in data['supported'])
```

And then you can print it pretty easily:

```
for s in stores:
    print(s)
```